# Remove sequential repeating rows from xts object

Tags: r, xts

Say I have the following XTS object containing Bid and Ask data:

```
   Time     Bid    Ask
   00:01    10     11
   00:02    10     11
   00:03    11     12
   00:04    12     13
   00:05    10     11
   00:06    10     11
   00:07    10     11

   00:08    9      12
   00:09    2      10
   00:10    4      5
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
   Time     Bid    Ask
   00:01    10     11
   00:03    11     12
   00:04    12     13
   00:05    10     11

   00:08    9      12
   00:09    2      10
   00:10    4      5
```

Rows should only be removed if they are the same as the previous entry. If there is a Bid or Ask change then nothing it is not removed, so simply taking out duplicates will not work.

This should be fairly simple as I have done this before, but I just cannot remember how and cannot find it.

Update:
I added some extra entries in my initial data and expected output.

Joshua's swearer is brilliant, but it depends on the function such as rowSums giving different results, but it breaks with 9 12.
I used the rowProds function from the matrixStats package which works, but obviously fails for my last 2 lines. Also, my sample the values in column one are smaller than in column 2. While that makes sense, it not a must so the function should work if the Ask was less than the Bid where both rowSums and rowProds would fail.
Is there a better row function that would always give a different result if anything is different, such as maybe a row hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using `rle()` on the sum of each row.

```
x <- structure(
  c(10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 11L),
  .Dim = c(7L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Bid", "Ask")),
  index = structure(1:7, tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "",
  tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"))
r <- rle(rowSums(x))
```

If you want the last observation in each group, you can just use `cumsum(r$lengths)` as the row index when subsetting.

```
R> x[cumsum(r$lengths),]
                    Bid Ask
1969-12-31 18:00:02  10  11
1969-12-31 18:00:03  11  12
1969-12-31 18:00:04  12  13
1969-12-31 18:00:07  10  11
```

Since you want the first observation of each group, you need to prepend the `r$lengths` vector with a `1` (you always want the first observation) and then remove the last element of `r$lengths`. Then call `cumsum()` on the result.

```
R> x[cumsum(c(1, head(r$lengths, -1))),]
                    Bid Ask
1969-12-31 18:00:01  10  11
1969-12-31 18:00:03  11  12
1969-12-31 18:00:04  12  13
1969-12-31 18:00:05  10  11
```

---

Good catch on the limitation of `rowSums()`. A robust solution is to `diff()` the bids and asks and select the rows where either is not zero.

```
d <- diff(x) != 0           # rows with price changes
d[1,] <- TRUE               # always select first observation
g <- cumsum(d$Bid | d$Ask)  # groups of repeats
r <- rle(as.numeric(g))     # run length encoding on groups

# now use the solution above
x[cumsum(c(1, head(r$lengths, -1))),]
```

Comment: That is brilliant and I will need some more time to figure out exactly how it works. I do believe the rowSums is a little limiting as if the next line was 00:08  9  12 the sum would be the same at 21. Fortunately the matrixStats package has a rowProds command which handles that better. Is there an even better option to ensure in does not remove rows by mistake? Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelE: Good catch on the bug. The updated answer is more robust and doesn't introduce additional dependencies.